# How to fetch data from Oracle cursor into a temporary table and then print out the data in SQLPlus?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, sqlperformance

I am fetching data from cursor in the way like this:

```
variable rc refcursor
spool file.txt
set timing on
exec :rc := someoraclepackage.somefunction(some,parameters,here)
set timing off
print rc
spool off
```

But I've identified a problem with `TIMING`. Some packages give me the real time of their execution, but some other not. They show me time like 120 miliseconds, and the real time of processing the package is for example 10 minutes.

I need the exact time of the package processing for performance testing.

All I have heard about the solution of this problem is:

1. Inserting the data from the cursor to a temporary table (database server side), to count the real package runtime.
2. Running a `select *` on the temporary table to fetch the data (jenkins side)

But I have no Idea where to start with putting the data from the cursor to a temporary table, and I don't know if this is the real solution of the problem...

Comment: The real time for the function call, or the time to retrieve the data from the ref cursor? That can be quite different, e.g. with piped rows. If you're trying to get the actual elapsed time, the overhead for the client may be of interest anyway, so timing the call and fetch from Jenkins might be more appropriate.

Comment: @AlexPoole The trick is that the timing we need has to be counted server-side. The results from Jenkins can be distorted by the web connection performance, air fluctations, bad weather etc. ;) Currently the idea is to count both times, time of the function call and time to retrieve the data from the function.

Comment: OK, so run this as a script on the server from SQL*Plus, redirected to a file (or set termout off); and include the `print` in the overall timing?